# IS there a different in WebService programming in 32bit and 64bit?

Tags: c#

IS there a different in WebService programming in 32bit and 64bit ?

under server 2003 (C# programming )

thank's in advance

Comment: Do you have something specific in mind?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is really no difference between a 32 and 64 bit C# Web Service program than there is for any other type of C# program.  The .Net framework was designed to be a mostly platform agnostic framework and it only creeps up in certain areas.  Namely

- PInvoke: Ideally this is written in a platform agnostic manner but it can be done incorrectly to be tied to a specific platform
- COM Interop: Native component may be tied to a particular architecture

Answer (score 1):

(to re-state Jared's reply in slightly different terms)

If you use pure .net code, then just compile for "Any CPU" (the default) and it will work in 32-bit and 64-bit environments.

However, if any part of your application (e.g. a C++/COM dll) is 32-bit, then you have to change the compile type to "x86" to force the entire application to run under WOW64 (as a 32-bit application), or you have to rebuild/get the dll in a 64-bit native form. Essentially you cannot mix 32-bit and 64-bit code in your application.